# How to add additional captions to the left side of each row?

Tags: tables, math-mode, graphics, formatting, captions

I'm trying on adding extra captions on top of the first row and to the left of each row, and I don't know how to add them to the left side of each row. This is the code I've tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption*{Caption for Figure 1}
        \label{fig:sub1}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hspace{5pt}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption*{Caption for Figure 2}
        \label{fig:sub2}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hspace{5pt}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption*{Caption for Figure 3}
        \label{fig:sub3}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hspace{5pt}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption*{Caption for Figure 4}
        \label{fig:sub4}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hspace{5pt}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption*{Caption for Figure 5}
        \label{fig:sub5}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}

    \vspace{10pt} % Add vertical space between the rows

    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hspace{5pt}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hspace{5pt}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hspace{5pt}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hspace{5pt}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.18\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is the output of the code:
[image]

This is what I want:
[image]

Comment: While you could do it adding more subfigures, I would just use a tabular.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372059/how-do-i-place-captions-rotated-alongside-an-image/372073?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C21.6281#372073 for example.

Comment: Do you mean adding subfigures with the words "captions 1" and "captions 2" inside them to the left side of each row? Because I just want to add text instead of adding entire subfigures

Comment: Yes, but you also need a constant horizontal space.  You could use `\makebox` instead.  You don't really need `\caption*` either, and subfigure is just a minipage with `\let\caption=\subcaption`.

Comment: I still don't know how to put the captions on the left side of the row, _You don't really need `\caption*` either_, the reason for using `\caption*` is that I don't want to start with "Figure" for every captions

Comment: Does anyone know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also made some gratuitous formatting changes.  Note that `\label` does not work with `\caption*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for valign
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.15\linewidth}
      \caption*{Caption 1}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.15\linewidth}
        \caption*{Caption for Figure 1}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.15\linewidth}
        \caption*{Caption for Figure 2}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.15\linewidth}
        \caption*{Caption for Figure 3}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.15\linewidth}
        \caption*{Caption for Figure 4}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.15\linewidth}
        \caption*{Caption for Figure 5}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}

    \vspace{\floatsep} % Add vertical space between the rows

    \begin{subfigure}{0.15\linewidth}
      \caption*{Caption 2}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.15\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.15\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.15\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.15\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.15\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This solution uses a tabular.  While this requires computing `\tabcolsep`, the result is simpler than the tabular* version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth/12}% 6*0.15=0.9
    \begin{tabular}{*6{m{0.15\textwidth}}}
      & {\raggedright Caption for Figure 1}
      & {\raggedright Caption for Figure 2}
      & {\raggedright Caption for Figure 3}
      & {\raggedright Caption for Figure 4}
      & {\raggedright Caption for Figure 5}
    \\[\abovecaptionskip]
      {\hfil Caption 1} 
      & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \\[\floatsep]
      {\hfil Caption 2}
      & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, another question is that in the second solution, are there any methods to reduce the size of the captions at the top of the figures because the captions are quite lengthy. Thanks

Comment: Smaller font?  Justification=centering?  \rotatebox?

Comment: Thanks! Small question: in the first solution, if the captions on the left side of each row get longer, they will be pushed to the top. How can I keep those captions in the middle of the row ? Thanks

Comment: My tests do not show such behavior.  The default for subfigure is [c], which grows both up and down equally.  You can see the baseline by adding `\llap{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}` at the rne end of a row.